# Why is the same file larger on my USB stick?

Tags: linux, usb

When I copy files to my USB-device, they seem to grow in size.

I have a directory called testdir containing a bunch of ascii text files. 
The original directory:

```
$ du -hs testdir
22M
```

I copied the directory to my usb-device

```
$ du -hs testdir
82M
```

I checked the contents. They are exactly the same. The only thing I can think about that differs is the filesystems:

```
$ lsblk -f
...
 sdb                                                        
└─sdb1 ext4           ce7a8f47-699d-450a-9391-932e75e6eb44 /
sdc                                                        
└─sdc1 vfat           F474B7AA74B76DCC                     /mnt/usbstick
...
```

Why is this?

Comment: Probably has something to do with the different types of file systems being used and the size of the "blocks".  I wouldn't exactly call that an answer though...sorry.  here's some links. I am curious to the answer here.  [1]http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/14409/difference-between-block-size-and-cluster-size [2] http://superuser.com/questions/510105/differnce-between-blocksize-and-bytesize-in-linux-unix-filesystems

Comment: If there were just a *small* difference, it might be due to the *allocation unit size* with which the stick is formatted, but a nearly 4:1 increase is a bit much, even if there were many small files.  Does *ls* show more detail for each file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Block size

Longer answer: The USB drive most likely has a larger block size than your hard drive. File systems by their very nature is incapable of using only parts of a block, and the result is that a whole block is used even if the amount of data is only a fraction of the block size.

Since you have, as you say, "a bunch of ascii text files", this amplifies the issue, as these are usually very small. For example, if your block size is 16Kb, a file will take at least that much space, regardless of its actual size.

you can see the partitions block size with this command (requires root):

`blockdev --getbsz /dev/XXXX`

....where XXX is the device node of the partition.